# I have a problem with my class when I create a PHP form using arrays

Tags: php, arrays

everything are right but when i put two tag same together second tag are create but not first one

```
<?php 
require 'header/security-class.php';

class SecureForm{

    function form($action ,$method ,$InputArray ,$button=false){
        global $security;
        $form = '';
        $form .= "<form action='$action' method='$method'>";
        $form .= "<input type='hidden' name='token' value= '". $security->GenerateTokens(3, 20) ."' />";

        foreach ($InputArray as $input=>$key){
            // for label elemnt
            //requier contect in attribute
            if($input == 'label' ){
                $form .= "<label ";
                foreach($key as $attribute=>$value){
                    $form .= $attribute."='".$value."' ";
                }
                $form .= ">";
                $form .= $key['content'];
                $form .="</label>";
            }else{
                //for input element
                //esay to make type by input:type
                //else you can make it in attrbuits

                $type = explode(':',$input);
                if($type[0] == "input")$elemnt = $type[0];
                if($type[0] == "input" and count($type) > 1 ){
                $form .= "<". $type[0] ." type ='". $type[1] ."' "; 
                }elseif($type[0] == "input" and count($type) > 1 ){
                    $form .= "<input ";
                }else{
                    $form .= "<$input ";
                }
                foreach($key as $attribute=>$value)
                $form .= $attribute."='".$value."' ";

                if($type[0] == "input"){
                    $form .= '/>';
                }else{
                    $form .= " ></$input>";
                }

            }
        }

        if(is_array($button)){
            $form .= '<button name="'.$button['name'].'" class="'.$button['class'].'">'.
            $button['content'].'</button>';
        }

        $form .= "</form>";

        return $form;
    }
}

$form = new SecureForm;

$InputArray = array(
    'input:text' => array(
        'id'=>'input',
        'class'=>'input',
        'max' =>'250'
    ),
    'input:text' => array(
        'name'=>'button',
        'value'=>'name',
        'id'   =>'button'
    )
);
echo $form->form('#','post',$InputArray );
```

//result

```
<input type="text" name="button" value="name" id="button">
```

//must be

```
<input type="text" id="input" class="input" max="250">
<input type="text" name="button" value="name" id="button">
```

what are wrong is here ?
because i test it in a a lot of code like
two textarea , hidden or input 
but i can't solve it

sorry but i must write anything because this issue

Comment: `$button` is an option argument to the method, it defaults to `false` (which is _not_ an array)... You did not even specify that argument, so how can you expect it to be an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwritting your array indexes.

```
$InputArray = array(
//  v----------v--------------- first index name
    'input:text' => array(
        'id'=>'input',
        'class'=>'input',
        'max' =>'250'
    ),
//  v----------v--------------- Same index name, the last value will be kept
    'input:text' => array(
        'name'=>'button',
        'value'=>'name',
        'id'   =>'button'
    )
);
```

that provides this `var_dump($InputArray);` :

```
array(1) {
  ["input:text"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "button"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "name"
    ["id"]=>
    string(6) "button"
  }
}
```

You might want to use a proper unique index and use the input type in a value separately such as :

```
$InputArray = array(
     array(
        'input_type' => 'input:text',
        'id'=>'input',
        'class'=>'input',
        'max' =>'250'
    ),
    array(
        'input_type' => 'input:text',
        'name'=>'button',
        'value'=>'name',
        'id'   =>'button'
    )
);
```

And then, in your loop, instead of using `$input`, use the proper index :

```
foreach ($InputArray as $value) {
...
    if($value['input_type'] == 'label' ) {
    ...
```